# Is it possible to find every possible combination of a tie for the electoral college in a program in a relatively short amount of time?

Tags: java, algorithm

My computer science teacher has assigned this problem to us, and just about everyone in our class up-roared over the complexity of the problem. We are only in Advanced Topics of Computer Science in High school and none of us really have no idea where to start, what algorithms to use or anything. We have determined that going straight though every possible combination, there would be 2^50th combinations to run though which is way WAY to big for really any of us to search for. I'm just curious if this is even possible to do at our low Computer Science skill level and if anyone personally thinks that this is a fair problem because our teacher still hasn't found a solution to his own problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Of course, that does not mean it will be quick or easy.

Comment: This question is hard to answer. See [P = NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) partially for a reason why this is hard to solve.

Comment: This is an excellent place to use dynamic programming. Look up the "partition problem" for a very fast algorithm for solving this problem.

Comment: Also, the question is relatively subjective. What do you mean by relatively short amount of time?

Comment: @EliSadoff like within at least 10 minutes I would say, I mean more than that I think might be too much

Comment: @EliSadoff It's not "hard" in any way, it's simple combinations: you have 50 values, each of which can go to one candidate or the other, and you have a bounds that eliminate many of them allowing early stoppage of calculations.

Comment: @DaveNewton But it's not. The electoral college is more complicated than that. There are many conditions that you are not accounting for, such as, popular vote ties, third party candidates, Maine's vote split, Nebraska's vote split, and Washington DC.

Comment: @EliSadoff I'd assumed (a) not taking vote splitting into account (which only adds a little more space) and (b) a limited number of candidates. The problem itself is still not hard, just large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution space is not really 2^50. A tie (assuming only two candidates) means 269-269. You can't get to 269 with only one state (or even only a handful of states) so you can immediately throw out all small subsets and all large subsets (winning every state also doesn't work). Furthermore, you only need to look for subsets that total 269 (because there are 538 total, that means that the complement of each of those sets is also 269).

That said, this still boils down to the subset sum problem:  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) so any solution will not scale well (unless you figure out how to do it in polynomial time, in which case you can claim $1,000,000). However, your problem is not to scale it; for the case of the US electoral college configuration (including vote splits in some states) it is not too large to figure out in a reasonable (< 10 mins as you say) amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

The solution space is smaller than it seems, since some states have the same number of electoral votes. For example, Florida and New York both have 29 electoral votes, so there are really just three cases, not four: both on the left, both on the right, and one on each side (which should be double-counted since this can happen in two ways). This reduces the number of cases to 6.2 * 10^9, over five orders of magnitude smaller than 2^51 (although, in exchange, there's a slight amount of extra work determining how many cases you're representing). Even without further optimization this is small enough to iterate over fairly quickly.

This [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) script

```
EV=[55,38,29,20,18,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3]~;
count=[1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,4,4,3,2,3,6,3,5,8];
s=0; forvec(v=vector(#count,i,[0,count[1]]), if(v*EV==269, s+=prod(i=1,#count, binomial(count[i],v[i])))); s
```

yields an answer within milliseconds.

This version doesn't attempt to handle third-party candidates, split state votes, etc.

Comment: This won't give the state configurations that led to the tie (by name) and, in that respect, the New York/Florida case SHOULD be double counted because those are two different configurations that will lead to a tie.

Comment: @Andrew No, this doesn't give the names, but it could be modified to give the names. If you look at the code you'll see that the New York/Florida case is properly double-counted (that's the product over binomial coefficients).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking only about the explanation above (I'm not terribly well versed in PARI). Adding the state names is trivial and having solved the problem without double counting the names can be added for both cases after the fact. I have up-voted your answer.

Comment: @Andrew You're right that the text could be confusing. I'll have to think about how it could be made clearer. Fundamentally, the idea is that you can loop through the count of each state/district until you find one which leads to a tie, and only then do you need to consider all the different ways to get to that configuration. (You can improve on this idea, but it's not needed since the problem is easy enough already.)